# Get post details by post id using open graph

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

By using this code:

```
$url2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$group_id}/feed?limit=500&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2));
```

I get json like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => bla bla bla bla bla bla
    [updated_time] => 2016-12-23T08:31:25+0000
    [id] => 000000000000_111111111111
)
```

The first part (0000...0) is the group id.
The second part (1111..1) is the post id.
I need the details of the post owner (id, name, profile picture).

You can help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API reference tells you which fields you can get for a post: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post

For example, to get the name of the creator:

`/{group-id}/feed?limit=500&fields=id,from`

...or if you want to get profile pictures too:

`/{group-id}/feed?limit=500&fields=id,from{id,name,picture}`

It is called "Declarative Fields" and came with v2.4 of the Graph API. You need to specify the fields you want to get in the result.